# Subrings of $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $p$ be prime. Suppose $R$ is the set of all rational numbers of the form $\frac{m}{n}$ where $m,n$ are integers and $p$ does not divide $n$.

Clearly then $R$ is a subring of $\mathbb{Q}$.

I now want to show that if $\frac{m}{n}$ belongs to any *proper* ideal of $R$ then $p|m$.

Can someone point me in the right direction.

Thanks

Comment: In other words, you're trying to show that $R$ is a local ring, with maximal ideal $pR$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINT: If $p\nmid m$, then $\frac{n}m\in R$.

Comment: I really don't see how this helps us. Because $\frac{m}{n}$ and $\frac{n}{m}$ are units in $R$ in this case can we deduce something?

Comment: @Mathmo To what ideals can an invertible element belong?

Comment: @Mathmo: Look at the $\frac{m}nR$, the ideal generated by $\frac{m}n$: $\frac{m}n\cdot\frac{n}m$ belongs to it, and therefore ... ?

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Right so if $p$ does not divide $m$ then $1 \in \frac{m}{n}R$ and so this ideal is equal to $R$ which means it can't be a proper ideal?

Comment: @Mathmo: That’s right.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott But does this work for any proper ideal as that's what I want. I can't follow the logic. If we suppose $\frac{m}{n}$ is in some ideal $J\subset R$ then if $p$ does not divide $m$ we have that $\frac{m}{n} R=R$. But how does this show us that $J$ is not proper?

Comment: @Mathmo: Because then $R=\frac{m}nR\subseteq J\subseteq R, and hence $J=R$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Yes! Thanks! This is great.

Comment: @Mathmo: You’re welcome!

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** If $p$ doesn't divide $m$, can you show that $m/n$ is a unit?

Answer (score 0):

Hint:  What happens if you assume that $m$ is divisible by $p$?

Answer (score 0):

You can view $R$ as the localization of the ring of integers outside $p$, meaning
$$R=\mathbb{Z}_{S}=\{\frac{m}{m}:m\in\mathbb{Z},n\in S\}$$
where $S\subseteq\mathbb{Z}$ is the multiplicative subset of $\mathbb{Z}$ given by $S:=\mathbb{Z}\setminus p\mathbb{Z}$.

Now, $\mathbb{Z}$ is a Dedekind domain (it is a PID), hence every localization of $\mathbb{Z}$ outside a prime $p$ is a DVR, meaning a PID and local (i.e only one maximal ideal). If $\frac{m}{n}$ belongs to a proper ideal of $R$, then it is contained in a maximal ideal of $R$. But $R$ is local and its unique maximal ideal is $p\mathbb{Z}_S$, which is the set of fractions $\frac{a}{b}$ with $a\in p\mathbb{Z}$ and $b\notin p\mathbb{Z}$. Thus $\frac{m}{n}$ belongs to $p\mathbb{Z}_S$, implying $m\in p\mathbb{Z}$.